# What's the difference between the Window.Loaded and Window.ContentRendered events

Tags: wpf, events, window

What's the difference between the `Window.Loaded` and `Window.ContentRendered` events in WPF?  Is the `ContentRendered` event called first?

The description of the `Window.ContentRendered` event [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered.aspx) just says

> Occurs after a window's content has been rendered.

The description of the `Window.Loaded` event [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) says

> Occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

I have a case where I want to set the window's `MaxHeight` to the height of the working area of the screen that is displaying my window.  Which event should I do it in?

Edit:

I think I found what I was looking for, but I'm even more confused now.  The `Loaded` event happens first and then the `ContentRendered` event happens.  In the book Programming WPF by Chris Sells & Ian Griffiths, it says that the `Loaded` event is

> Raised just before the window is shown

While the 'ContentRendered` event is

> Raised when the window's content is visually rendered.

This contradicts what the MSDN documentation says about the `Loaded` event:

> Occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

This is even more confusing now.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think there is little difference between the two events. To understand this, I created a simple example to manipulation:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="LoadedAndContentRendered.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Name="MyWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="525"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered"     
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Grid Name="RootGrid">        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ContentRendered");
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
}
```

In this case the message `Loaded` appears the first after the message `ContentRendered`. This confirms the information in the documentation.

In general, in WPF the `Loaded` event fires if the element:

> is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

Since in WPF the `Window` is the same element, but it should be generally content that is arranged in a root panel (for example: `Grid`). Therefore, to monitor the content of the `Window` and created an `ContentRendered` event. Remarks from MSDN:

> If the window has no content, this event is not raised.

That is, if we create a `Window`:

```
<Window x:Class="LoadedAndContentRendered.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name="MyWindow"        
    ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered" 
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" />
```

It will only works `Loaded` event.

With regard to access to the elements in the `Window`, they work the same way. Let's create a `Label` in the main `Grid` of `Window`.  In both cases we have successfully received access to `Width`:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ContentRendered: " + SampleLabel.Width.ToString());
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Loaded: " + SampleLabel.Width.ToString());
}
```

As for the `Styles` and `Templates`, at this stage they are successfully applied, and in these events we will be able to access them.

For example, we want to add a `Button`:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ContentRendered: " + SampleLabel.Width.ToString());

    Button b1 = new Button();
    b1.Content = "ContentRendered Button";
    RootGrid.Children.Add(b1);
    b1.Height = 25;
    b1.Width = 200;
    b1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Loaded: " + SampleLabel.Width.ToString());

    Button b1 = new Button();
    b1.Content = "Loaded Button";
    RootGrid.Children.Add(b1);
    b1.Height = 25;
    b1.Width = 200;
    b1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
}
```

In the case of `Loaded` event, `Button` to add to `Grid` immediately at the appearance of the `Window`. In the case of `ContentRendered` event, `Button` to add to `Grid` after all its content will appear.

Therefore, if you want to add items or changes before load `Window` you must use the `Loaded` event. If you want to do the operations associated with the content of `Window` such as taking screenshots you will need to use an event `ContentRendered`.

Comment: It would be interested to see what events are raised when the window redraws, for example, minimize the window and then restore it.  Is the window's `Loaded` event raised again?  Is the `ContentRendered` the only one raised?

Comment: @Tony Vitabile: Yes, these events will work once, at the start of the `Window` (minimizing and restore not affect). Usually, `Loaded` fires a second time an item is physically removed from the logical tree, and introduced again, then it will fires.

Comment: I've been testing this and it's my experience that the `Loaded` event fires before the window is rendered, while the `ContentRendered` event fires after it has been rendered.  Interestingly, when `Loaded` fires, the layout & measure passes seem to be complete as `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` are set.  The window just hasn't been drawn yet.

Comment: @Tony Vitabile: Yes it is possible. My answer to you is not suitable? If you have any questions about the answer, please ask, because I might miss something.

Comment: The behavior is the behavior.  I'm just trying to make sure I understand what's going on so I can put code in the right places.  Thank you, you've helped a lot.

Comment: For those coming here with ContextRendered firing to early: You might consider waiting for LayoutUpdated

Comment: Maybe I'm nitpicking, but accessing Width doesn't prove much, ActualWidth would interest me more to know that layout was actually done.

Answer (score 56):

If you visit this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms748948(v=vs.100)#window-lifetime-events and scroll down to Window Lifetime Events it will show you the event order.

Open:

1. SourceInitiated
2. Activated
3. Loaded
4. ContentRendered

Close:

1. Closing
2. Deactivated
3. Closed

Comment: Thanks for this info, its a old one but fixed quite a few problems that I was having with WPF and multi threads :D

Answer (score 14):

If you're using data binding, then you need to use the ContentRendered event.

For the code below, the Header is NULL when the Loaded event is raised.
However, Header gets its value when the ContentRendered event is raised.

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding NewGame_Name}" Command="{Binding NewGameCommand}" />
```

Comment: This is the important difference. The binding is done. So registiering to handlers like textchanged, checkboxchanged get fired when you register in Loaded event. But already have been fired once when you register in ContentRendered.

Comment: From what I understand the Bindings should have been evaluated when the Loaded event is fired. Have you checked the value of the Header on the Loaded raised by MenuItem or the parent Window? The loaded event gets fired from the top-down - Window first and then elements inside it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikehillberg/the-loaded-event-and-the-initialized-event

Answer (score 1):

Window class inheritance

- Object
- DispatcherObject
- DependencyObject
- Visual
- UIElement
- FrameworkElement <- this is where **Loaded** lives
- Control
- ContentControl
- Window <- this is where **ContentRendered** lives

The difference is that Loaded fires when the Window (as a FrameworkElement object) **itself** is ready
However, a Window (by **itself**) is just a title-bar with minimize and maximize buttons, and a big empty space in the middle...

The big empty space is a ContentControl, so after the Window is Loaded and ready, we then turn our attention to the "important" bit, the Window's Content.

Once the Window's Content is rendered onto the screen, then ContentRendered fires.

NOTE: If the window has no content, the ContentRendered event is **not** fired.

Answer (score -1):

This is not about the difference between `Window.ContentRendered` and `Window.Loaded` but about what how the `Window.Loaded` event can be used:

I use it to avoid splash screens in all applications which need a long time to come up.

```
    // initializing my main window
    public MyAppMainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the event
        this.ContentRendered += MyAppMainWindow_ContentRendered;
    }

    private void MyAppMainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ... comes up quick when the controls are loaded and rendered

        // unset the event
        this.ContentRendered -= MyAppMainWindow_ContentRendered;

        // ... make the time comsuming init stuff here
    }
```