# Returning values from SQL to a WPF form - am I doing it correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am creating a form with several calculations from the same table (in this case).  The code works fine, but I could with with some guidance to make sure I am doing things efficiently:

When the form loads, I simply want two textblocks to be populated with counts.  I know that I will need to put some error checking in, but outside of that - is this a good way of doing it?

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int intCount = ReturnNumber("SELECT COUNT(ActivityID) FROM tblActivity WHERE [Activity_Category] = 'Productivity'");
    TxtBlockProductivityPerc.Text = intCount.ToString();

    intCount = ReturnNumber("SELECT COUNT(ActivityID) FROM tblActivity WHERE [Activity_Category] = 'Revenue'");
    TxtBlockRevenuePerc.Text = intCount.ToString();    
}

public int ReturnNumber(string StrQuery)
{
    string cs = ClsVariables.StrDb;
    string cmdText = StrQuery;
    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdText, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.close();
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you are not developing an application in MVVM style, such an approach is not bad, but it's just my opinion. Here a couple of my comments:

- In this situation, I think better to use event [`Window.ContentRendered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered.aspx), because [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event is triggered when loading `Window` as Control, and the ContentRendered event  triggered when rendering the contents of the `Window`. But the big difference no between them [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452756/whats-the-difference-between-the-window-loaded-and-window-contentrendered-event).
- You have to be separately stored query strings, because every time we need to change them, you'll have to climb into your function, which is not convenient.
- Add to the functions that work with SQL server prefix `FromSQL`, in your case will be something like this: `ReturnNumberFromSQL()`.
- You do not need a temporary variable, you can call the function and immediately get a result from it.

My pseudo example:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Test1Sql = "Test1 SQL query"; // stored separately
    string Test2Sql = "Test2 SQL query"; // stored separately

    MyTextBlock1.Text = ReturnNumberFromSQL(Test1Sql).ToString();
    MyTextBlock2.Text = ReturnNumberFromSQL(Test2Sql).ToString();
}

public int ReturnNumberFromSQL(string StrQuery)
{
    return 777;
}
```

And think on the expense of having to store procedures that do not work with GUI *separately* in the appropriate class.

Comment: Thank you Anatoliy - that makes a lot of sense.  I'm pretty new to C#/WPF and do want to start using MVVM - but every time I come across a video/book - I quickly feel out of my depth (currently).

Comment: @AndyDB: I think the transition to MVVM should not be spontaneous, the programmer must mature for this. Learn [`SOLID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles and OOP principles and it will be easier to understand other patterns, in particular MVVM.