# WPF window_loaded event triggered but window is not loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an problem. I have tabitems and if these items have images in the in the header, the window_loaded event is triggered before the window become visible. If the tabitems are just plain old tabitems, the window is visible before the loaded event. Does anyone know why is that happening?

Comment: Could you please provide your XAML and window constructor code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18452756/934912

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18452756/934912), I believe that you really should be using `Window.ContentRendered` instead of `Window.Loaded`

Answer (score 0):

@StillLearnin thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Instead of using `Window_Loaded` event I used `Window_ContentRendered`